# How do I reset or override IE CSS filters?

Tags: css, filter, internet-explorer

I'm using the proprietry MS 'filter' property to try and create a non ugly equivalent to css3 text-shadow and box-shadow;

I was actually doing really well until I hit this problem. It looks like when I apply a filter to a div inside another div which also has a filter the filter effects end up being combined on the child object.

I've tried using filter:none; to do a reset but no joy. I've also tried different variations on the syntax, ie "-ms-filter: 'progid:...Glow()'", "filter: progid:...Glow()", "filter: Glow()", etc..

Testing in IE8

Comment: This works for me: `filter:;`

Comment: filter:; doesn't work with lessphp css preprocessor, filter:-; does though.

Comment: use `filter: ;` . this I guess will force the IE to remove the property all together as it is not a valid value.

Comment: Using SCSS, I had to use `filter:none;` to avoid Syntax errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had some success by positioning the children absolute or relative. This didn't seem to work earlier though so it may break again once I get more complicated

I think once a parent has a filter applied all of it's children essentially become directx surfaces internally. You can still select text but it lags. I think text selection is a hack which makes each letter a seperate surface. It's a shitty mess which goes a long way to explaining why the browser in general and filters in particular are so buggy.

Answer (score 95):

There is boolean attribute *enabled*, for which you can set **false** or **true**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Example:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)";
```

Comment: Thanks! gradient filters for buttons don't play nicely with then having certain buttons with background images - the filter comes over the image...

Answer (score 20):

The -ms-filter property is a non-standard, browser-specific CSS entry and as such requires that its parameter is enclosed with quotation marks. So -ms-filter: "none" will work just fine.

Answer (score 16):

try this:

filter: -;

Comment: Worked for me in IE7 while -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)"; didn't. Thx

Comment: @SimonArnold "-ms-filter" is only supported by IE8 and up; IE7 only supports the "filter" attribute. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using HTML5 you may want to go down the route of using

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="gtie9 modern">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

and in your CSS use something like:

```
.ie9 .element {filter: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to [enable/disable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532876(VS.85).aspx) the filter(s)?

Comment: it doesn't work, you can't override a parents filter from the child.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way is display:inline-block (applying white-space:nowrap to the container). But it seems to work bad with IE7 and lower