# Equivalent to text-shadow in IE

Tags: css, shadow

I have this in my CSS:

```
body.transparent {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px #000, 1px 0 # 000, 0 1px #000, -1px 0 # 000;
}
body.transparent a {
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

But it doesn't work on IE. How do it solve this? Is there any equivalent for IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Mojo: [An Option to Mimic CSS3 Text Shadow in Internet Explorer](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-text-shadow-ie/).

```
filter: glow(color=black,strength=5);
```

The site also lists some other workarounds with JavaScript.

Comment: i tryed it with filter: glow, but it caused me other issues (like me not being able to override it for body.transparent a {})

Comment: Have you tried `enabled` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532995%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Check this post: [How do I reset or override IE CSS filters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768161/how-do-i-reset-or-override-ie-css-filters)

Comment: perfect for ie.  adding this one to the one i had for chrome i got a crossbrowser soluction! thanks