# text-shadow for Safari and IE

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent to text-shadow in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195948/equivalent-to-text-shadow-in-ie)

I have this text shadow that works fine in Safari.  But it doesn't in IE.  How do I get the same shadow effect for Safari and for IE?

```
<a class="feast_info" title="title">feast</a>

.feast_info {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: green;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #303030;
}
```

Comment: a simple google search will help you, type text-shadow in IE

Comment: How about just telling folks that have IE (before 9?) or other older browsers to "get a better browser"? Every cross-browser hack is a tradeoff, and it's not clear this one's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of Internet Explorer do not implement those CSS constructs. You can use this in your CSS instead:

**Internet Explorer 8:**

```
#text_block_id {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=3, OffY=3, Color=#99cc99)";
}
```

**Internet Explorer 5.5-7:**

```
#text_block_id {
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=3, OffY=3, Color=#99cc99);
}
```

Add those two lines to your CSS and you'll have support for Internet Explorer 5.5 through 8.

Answer (score 1):

`text-shadow` is not supported by IE, however there are some suggestions [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/textshadow.html) on emulating the effect. To be completely fair though, [the result is not impressive](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/fRNkT/2/).

I would strongly suggest sticking with the concept of graceful degradation and discarding non-critical effects on browsers that do not support them. Should it be an absolute must (i.e. for brand recognition) and if the scope of its application allows (i.e. has to be present only in one place) you could feed pre-rendered content to IE as a png image.

Comment: Great answer, browser degradation is the only way to fly...P.S. the jsfiddle link is dead.

Comment: @Kieron: thanks! link fixed, but as I said result is *not* impressive :)

Answer (score 0):

This will apply the `text-shadow` in the most common browsers *(see the test list below)*:

**CSS**

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #444444;
filter: dropshadow(color=#444444, offx=1, offy=1);
filter: shadow(color=#444444,direction=135,strength=2);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#444444,direction=135,strength=2)";
```

**Tested on:**

- Google Chrome 19.0.1084.46 m
- Firefox 3.6.16
- Firefox 12.0
- Opera 11.64
- Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702
- Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421IC

Answer (score -4):

for safari try putting this

```css
-webkit-text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #303030;
```

Comment: You appear not to have even read the question.