# CSS Gradient not working in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

This is the code that is not working in IE9 but is working in Mozilla. If I uncheck that in Developer tools, it is showing the given color.

How to fix this to work in IE9.

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 )
```

Comment: does this rule have `filter:` before it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SVG`

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2Y1ZjVmNSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNlNWU1ZTUiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
```

---

**Try** to generate by http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ *(for cross-browser)*

```
background: #f5f5f5;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f5f5f5), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 );
```

**And add this on your HTML :** *(to stop using `filter` on IE9 and use SVG instead)*

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

PS : Change `.gradient` to your using element

Answer (score -1):

You need to use:

```
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 )"
```

source: [How do I reset or override IE CSS filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768161/how-do-i-reset-or-override-ie-css-filters)